# avalonDock unloads content while docking

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, avalondock

It seems that AvalonDock unloads and reloads the content of its document windows anytime the window is manipulated with docking, or undocking.  Is it possible to turn that off?

In my case, I'm displaying a live video stream and I need to keep it playing while the window is set to float, or redocked.

Also it seems that the documentation for AvalonDock 2.0 is not complete.  Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong spot.  All I was able to find on codeplex is this: [AvalonDock 2.0 getting started guide PART 1](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock%202.0%20Getting%20Start%20Guide&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently. When showing a map on an anchorable pane, the markers were deleted at docking/undocking the pane.
I wrote on the AvalonDock page and in the map viewer (GMaps) developer site. The issue seems to be that the component (anchorables or documents in tab controls) destroys all the childs.
You can see it here: [Issue tracker](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/workitem/16071)

My solution was to handle the layout change (detect when the window is docked, floatin as a window...etc) and act in consequence.

Documentation for AvalonDock 2.0 is not available... The only documentation I recommend is the samples provided by the developers (see MVVM sample [here](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/releases/view/98689)).
Fortunately the project should be more active now because it became part of the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) . Maybe Xceed could take care of a proper documentation.

Hope this helps.